# PDO Query method only working when one condition in the where clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to use the following Query method in my db class to query the database with a prepared statement. The SQL appears to work fine in MySQL but in the prepared statement only works when there is one condition after the where but I need it to work with three conditions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**DB Class - Query Method**

```
// Generic query method.
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    // reset to ensure an error from a previous query is not returned. 
    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

// Calling query method 
// Method to check if the activity is available at the requested date and time.
public function checkDateTimeAvailability($name, $date, $time) {
    $result = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE name = ? AND act_date = ? AND
    time_from = ?", array($name, $date, $time));
    var_dump($result);
    if(!empty($result)){
        echo "query successful";
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: More information please. Are any errors thrown? No data shown? You sure the query returns results (not 0 - no results)? Also, how are you calling this? What does `$name, $date, $time` look like?

Comment: No errors thrown. This is how i call the method if(!$activity->checkDateTimeAvailability($act_name, $date, $time){

Comment: Query returns 2 rows in MYSQL but none in php. $name, $date and $time are all string values.

Comment: The var dump returns object(DB)#3 (6) { ["_pdo":"DB":private]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } ["_query":"DB":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#6 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(80) "SELECT * FROM `activity` WHERE 'name' = ? AND 'act_date' = ? AND 'time_from' = ?" } ["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false) ["_results":"DB":private]=> array(0) { } ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(0) ["_data":"DB":private]=> NULL } query successful